# JSON Storage path

Tags: javascript, json

I want to generate a .json file which holds some portion of a a larger DB on load of a web page, so where is the .json file going to be saved? Will it behave similar to XML and Cookies and go into the browser cache? The temporary internet files folder?

You could boil it down and say that I don't really understand JSON, and could use some pointers...

EDIT: To make things clearer:

I have a DB with data in it, and I want this data to be available to the client in the form of 'search suggestions', so when the client enters something in an input field, a list of suggestions appears - This list is to be drawn from the .json file, and not the DB... I'm using HTML, and plain JS here...

Comment: We need more information. What language(s) are you using? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: K mate, edit made, more information added... Do lemme know if you need more clarification...

Comment: Lol, wait.. So its wrong to ask general knowledge questions here on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends, if you want to cache it or not.

look at jquery's documentation

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Hey, I do want the data to be cached... Basically, when the user visits my site for the first time, I want to trigger a XHR request via a web worker (to allow concurrency) and create a .json file holding values from the DB... Then everytime the user interacts with the input element, the .json file is queried instead of sending a round-trip request to the server.

Comment: Lol, fair enough mate... Thanks for the heads up... I really need to start doing my homework before I come crying to SO... But y'all are so helpful! Lol...